# pandas comparision operator `==` not working as expected when column contain `List` instead `Tuple`

Tags: python, pandas, list, tuples, comparison-operators

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'Li':[[1,2],[5,6],[8,9]],'Tu':[(1,2),(5,6),(8,9)]}
df
       Li      Tu
0  [1, 2]  (1, 2)
1  [5, 6]  (5, 6)
2  [8, 9]  (8, 9)
```

Working fine for `Tuple`

```py
df.Tu == (1,2)
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Tu, dtype: bool
```

When its `List` it gives value error

```py
df.Li == [1,2]
```

> ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that pandas is considering `[1, 2]` as a *series-like* object and trying to compare each element of `df.Li` with each element of `[1, 2]`, hence the error:

> ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

You cannot compare a list of size two with a list of size 3 (`df.Li`). In order to verify this you can do the following:

```
print(df.Li == [1, 2, 3])
```

**Output**

```
0    False
1    False
2    False
Name: Li, dtype: bool
```

It doesn't throw any error and works, but returns `False` for all as expected. In order to compare using list, you can do the following:

```
# this creates an array where each element is [1, 2]
data = np.empty(3, dtype=np.object)
data[:] = [[1, 2] for _ in range(3)]

print(df.Li == data)
```

**Output**

```
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Li, dtype: bool
```

All in all it seems like a **bug** in the pandas side.

Comment: "So here it's considering `Tuple` as scalar and `List` as sequence" is it right?

Comment: @anonymous Yes I believe it so.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `list`s aren't hashable, so it is necessary to compare `tuple`s:

```
print (df.Li.map(tuple) == (1,2))
0     True
1    False
2    False
Name: Li, dtype: bool
```

Or in list comprehension:

```
mask = [tuple(x) == (1,2) for x in df.Li]
#alternative
mask = [x == [1,2] for x in df.Li]
print (mask)
[True, False, False]
```

If all lists have the same lengths:

```
mask = (np.array(df.Li.tolist()) == [1,2]).all(axis=1)
print (mask)
[ True False False]
```

Comment: Got it. I just  wanted to know explanation why `list` not worked. this is also worked for me `df.Li.apply(lambda x:(x==[1,2]))`

Answer (score 0):

My column 'vectors' contained numpy ndarrays and I got the same error when I want to compare to another ndarray 'centroid'. The following works for numpy ndarrays:

```
df['vectors'].apply(lambda x: ((vec==centroid).sum() == centroid.shape[0]))
```

Which also works for Lists:

```
df.Li.apply(lambda x: x==[1,2])
```